# Swift: click inside programmatically generated view inside table

Tags: swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

Tried many things, but none of it worked.

My current views hierarchy:

- TableView Cell
- Vertical Stack View
- Programmatically generated View - gesture recognizer not fired

  ```
  let vContainer = UIView()
  vContainer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
  vContainer.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
  vContainer.backgroundColor = .red
  //Some view generation inside box is skipped (can be seen on image)
  self.vsvViewContainer.addArrangedSubview(vContainer)
  var tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(showValuePicker(sender:)))
  vContainer.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
  ```

later in class:

```
    @objc private func showValuePicker(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("showValuePicker")
    }
```

[image]

Red box is View, where i want to add click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a problem...

"self" was pointing to View Generating class, that has no relations to View Controller

Passing click events directly to the View Controller solved problem

Answer (score 1):

Why have you specified the target to be `nil`?

at:

```
var tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: nil, action: #selector(showValuePicker(sender:)))
```

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizer/1624211-init):

> **Target**
>
> An object that is the recipient of action messages sent by the
>   receiver when it recognizes a gesture. nil is not a valid value.

Can you try adding `self` as the target?

Comment: It could possibly be something that you've added on top of your view, that recognises taps instead. Can you try disabling user interaction for the subviews inside the view, and see if you're lucky?

Comment: Also, I'm curious as to why your `tapRecognizer` is declared a variable. You're modifying it later for something?

Answer (score 0):

Add `tapRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false` to your code

```
self.vsvViewContainer.addArrangedSubview(vContainer)
var tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(showValuePicker(sender:)))
tapRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false
vContainer.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
```

Comment: Added more details

Comment: Change target to `self` from `nil` if `showValuePicker` is in your class as well